# How to remove only one instance of specified character in string

Tags: python, string, split

If I have a list of strings such as the following:

```
"apple.test.banana", "test.example","example.example.test".
```

Is there a way to return only "test.banana" and "example.test"?

I need to check and see if there are two dots, and if there are, return only the value described above.

I attempted to use:

```
string="apple.test.banana"
dot_count=0
for i in string:
    if i==".":
        dot_count=dot_count+1
if dot_count>1:
    string.split(".")[1]
```

But this appears to only return the string "test".

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what's the contents of `string.split(".")`? you want both `[1]` and `[2]` if i understand what you've described as the output you want

Comment: `string.count('.')` may help

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right, except for the last line, which sould say `'.'.join(string.split(".")[1:])`.

Also, instead of the `for` loop, you can just use `.count()`: `dot_count = string.count('.')` (this doesn't affect anything, just makes your code easier to read)

So the program becomes:

```py
string = "apple.test.banana"
dot_count = string.count('.')
if dot_count > 1:
    print('.'.join(string.split(".")[1:]))
```

Which outputs: `test.banana`